# Bower install stuck at the json output: "message": "Answer",

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, npm, bower, webstorm

There are two issues that I am facing basically, while using Intellij

1. I dont understand why the output of bower install is a bunch of json messages. When I do bower install in my Webstorm, I see single line statements and prompts if I have to specify a version.

   ```
   {
   "level": "action",
   "id": "resolve",
   "message": "git://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys.git#~1.7.0",
   "data": {
       "endpoint": {
       "name": "angular-hotkeys",
       "source": "chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys",
       "target": "~1.7.0"
    }, {
       "type": "input",
       "message": "Answer",
       "name": "prompt",
       "level": "prompt"
    }
   ```
2. My bower install just gets stuck at the json mentioned above point like its looking for a prompt. I am not able to write anything and actually it does not ask me anything about what version I need or questions like that.

How can I get the standard output format for bower install?

My bower.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.5",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.5",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.5.5",
    "some-other-application": "~0.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your package.json? Did you tried to type `CTRL+C` when it got stuck in console? Does it stops then?

Comment: So I am not using a package.json. Is that important? No it does not stop with CTRL+R. It only stops with CTRL+C

Comment: A i meaned `CTR+C` `R` was a typo. No it is nor important, but can you then show your bower.json?

Comment: Updated bower.json

Comment: Please check the description again for bower.json

Comment: Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: the problem is not clear from your description. What is this first json? How do you run bower install in WebStorm - do you use built-in terminal, or? Does the same command work in your system terminal?

Comment: I can use both built-in  terminals and git bash and it works fine in webstorm. The issue is with intellij actually - where it shows json output

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured this out.

I had to remove "json": "bower.json" from .bowerrc file

Comment: I had this exact same issue and this fix worked for me, any idea why? It was working for the longest time before this fix.

Comment: This makes skipped your bower.json configuration. After then, it asks you required dependencies one by one.

Comment: @Jags check out my answer, maybe it could solve your problem without having to remove anything from .bowerrc file

Answer (score 0):

When you specify dependencies for your app via Bower, some of the packages might rely on different versions of the same library. You will have to resolve what version of libraries you want in your app.

If you configure you Bower using *"json": "bower.json"* inside *.bowerrc* file, Bower will expect those resolutions to be inside *bower.json* file. This means that you must have "*resolutions*" property inside *bower.json* file.

So, if you don't want to change your *.bowerrc* file:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.5",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.5",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.5.5",
    "some-other-application": "~0.0.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.5",
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikola, this looks promising but I have `resolutions` in my bower.json file with a similar setup (only `angular` in there rather than additionally including jquery), and it still hangs on message/name/level. Any suggestions?